# Markov chain factorisation

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^4$ be a Markov chain with $t$ denoting the time index. Simplify the following factorisation.
>   $$\Pr(X_4)\Pr(X_3|X_4)\Pr(X_2|X_3,X_4)\Pr(X_1|X_2,X_3,X_4)$$

I really don't know how Markov chains work, so some direction on how to factorise this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the definition of conditional probability repeatedly, and you'll get
$$
\Pr(X_4)\Pr(X_3|X_4)\Pr(X_2|X_3,X_4)\Pr(X_1|X_2,X_3,X_4)=\Pr(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)
\tag1
$$
Now reverse the subscripts in (1) to get another identity:
$$
\Pr(X_1)\Pr(X_2|X_1)\Pr(X_3|X_2,X_1)\Pr(X_4|X_3,X_2,X_1)=\Pr(X_4,X_3,X_2,X_1)\tag2
$$
But the RHS of (1) is the same as the RHS of (2). And, by the Markov property, the LHS of (2) simplifies to
$$
\Pr(X_1)\Pr(X_2|X_1)\Pr(X_3|X_2)\Pr(X_4|X_3)
$$

Comment: Is it not $\Pr(X_4)\Pr(X_3|X_4)\Pr(X_2|X_3)\Pr(X_1|X_2)$?

Comment: @Will If the time index is $t$ then the 'natural' order to observe the variables is $X_1$ first, then $X_2$, then $X_3$, etc. so the Markov property would say $P(X_{t+1}\mid X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_t) = P(X_{t+1}| X_t)$. In other words "the distribution tomorrow given today and the past is the same as the distribution tomorrow given today"